# How To Access AngularJS Scope From Javascript When Wrapped in an IFFE

Tags: android, angularjs

I'm writing an Android app, in which I need to invoke some javascript to interact with my AngularJS application.

Normally, I would write some code like the following:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("theNameOfTheElement")).scope().nameOfFunction();
```

However, if the scope of that element is written within an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), then it seems as though the angular scope is no longer available to outside vanilla javascript...

This obviously poses a problem if my team is following the John Papa style guide for our AngularJS code.

How would I expose the scope to outside javascript, or expose a public API to native javascript?